# Different skills and levels of a Pau in Farscape

Tags: farscape

In *Farscape* a Pau priest is supposed to be able to advance in ranks to different levels. Apparently each level can grant a new ability. Zhaan was a 10th level pau, and I know they mentioned something being 12th (to the point where I am at).

From my research online there isn't currently an upper limit.

What are the known levels a Pau can achieve and the skills associated with each one?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I do not have permission yet to create a tag, so I just picked what I could. Thanks for adding that.

Comment: The problem with tags is that if someone doesn't create a second question tagged Farscape it in a few weeks it will get auto deleted.